# Makefile: compile .o from .c files

Tags: c, makefile

I do not have much experience with Makefiles, so the answer may be obvious. However, I was not able to find what I am looking for in the GNU make manual or elsewhere on stackoverflow. I have run into this issue a few times, so I have made an example project to demonstrate it.

I have directories:

- src/ for .c files
- build/ for the library being built
- obj/ for all .o files (one being compiled from a different project)

What it looks like:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 sam None 0 Jan  5 15:43 build
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 sam None 0 Jan  5 15:43 obj
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 sam None 0 Jan  5 15:42 src
```

My Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.c)
SOURCE_OBJECTS=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

OBJECTS=$(wildcard obj/*.o)

HASHSRC=/cbib/libhash/src/hash.c

TARGET=target.a

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

obj/hash.o: $(HASHSRC)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

The rule

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
```

catches all .o files in the obj/ directory. However I only want it to catch the files listed in SOURCE_OBJECTS, and compile them from their corresponding files in the src/ directory. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OBJECTS=$(wildcard obj/*.o)` is empty, because [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) only returns existing files. You should depend on `$(SOURCE_OBJECTS)` in `$(TARGET)`.

When dealing with multiple input sources you can [narrow down the selection](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
# dest files        dest pattern  source pattern
$(SOURCE_OBJECTS):  obj/%.o:      src/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

There are further minor errors (or shortcomings) in the Makefile. E.g. who creates the directory `obj/`? For this you can [depend](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) on the directory like:

```
obj/%.o: | obj/

obj/:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... thanks for the quick response!